# Automatically update GitHub wiki based on repository markdown files

Tags: github, wiki, github-actions

I'm fairly new to GitHub and I've been trying to get the GitHub Wiki associated with a project to get the content from the main repository with no success.

Online there are guides on how to do this on Microsoft Azure [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/publish-repo-to-wiki?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser), but for some reason, I cannot find anything similar for GitHub. I am not sure where to ask this question so I came to the trusted StackOverflow community.

Basically I have a repository where we are uploading a series of markdown documents (see [giovannellilab/protocols](https://github.com/giovannellilab/protocols)) and I would like the content of the wiki for the same project to be updated with pages coming from the repository. Each markdown file in the repository becomes its own wiki page. Ideally, the wiki will get automatically updated every time we push something new to the repo or we merge a new pull request.
So far I have not found an easy to implement a solution.

I've also tried to use a GitHub Action found in the marketplace, [SwiftDocOrg](https://github.com/SwiftDocOrg/) with no success. I'm new to GitHub-actions and even follwing the guide I could not make this work. 
Here the content of my .yml page:

```
- name: Publish to GitHub Wiki
  uses: SwiftDocOrg/github-wiki-publish-action@1.0.0
  with:
    # A path to the directory of files to publish
    path: giovannellilab/protocols
```

The action is failing each time (obviously something is wrong/missing, but I cannot figure out what).

Any suggestions on how to make it work in GitHub?
Any other place where I can host documentation pulling directly from a GitHub repository?
Any other better way to implement this?

Thank you very much,
Don

Comment: As a reference for the future, I've abandoned the idea of using the GitHub wiki and I am using https://readthedocs.org/ to convert the markdown repository into a readable wiki at every update.